# how to implement wait or pause in background. User should not be prompted to select yes button to dial extension number while a call in android

Tags: android

I am developing apps for my organization which will connect to any employee desk phone after dialing his/her extension after main organization number. and this extension is saved in application db. suppose main contact number is "123456789" and then ext "234#" is required to connect an employee.

In Main Activity we have code like this:

```
Intent newIntent=new Intent();
newIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
newIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 123456789;234#"));
```

But above lines of code ask the user to send extra tones(extension: 2343) via option like "Yes/No". On selecting "Yes" button, the extension will be dialled. But my requirement is to dial extension without prompting the user on the screen to "send the message of the following tune" with an option "yes/no". Either "yes" should be selected automatically in background or extension number should be dialled automatically in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root access in the devices? Try to use a keyevent which press "Yes" button. 
Example:

```
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    try { // Run Script

        proc = runtime.exec("su");

        command = "input keyevent 20";
        osw.write(command);
        osw.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (osw != null) {
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        if (proc != null)
            proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No root access is not always available at run-time in every device. I need generic code which will dial extension(ex: 234#) in background without any user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Current line of code must be working below API 23, But after API 23 you can't start call automatically by trigger of call intent.

You can try it with emergency numbers for example.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But this is not my requirement what you have answered.